# how to get the text from stack of notifications android

Tags: android, android-notifications, whatsapp, notification-listener

please help me I am trying to get text from stack of notifications. I am getting following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mActions in class 
Landroid/app/Notification$BuilderRemoteViews; (declaration of 
'android.app.Notification$BuilderRemoteViews' appears in 
 /system/framework/framework.jar)
```

I am using NotificationListenerService and

```java
    private List<String> getMessages(Notification notification) {
        RemoteViews views = notification.bigContentView;
        if (views == null) views = notification.contentView;
        if (views == null) return null;
        List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();


        try {


            Field field = views.getClass().getDeclaredField(Constants.ACTIONS);
            field.setAccessible(true);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayList<Parcelable> actions = (ArrayList<Parcelable>) field.get(views);

            for (Parcelable p : actions) {
                Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
                p.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
                parcel.setDataPosition(0);
                int tag = parcel.readInt();
                if (tag != 2) continue;
                parcel.readInt();

                String methodName = parcel.readString();
                if (methodName == null) {
                    continue;
                } else if (methodName.equals(Constants.SET_TEXT)) {
                    parcel.readInt();

                    methodName.getBytes();
                    String gettingText = TextUtils.CHAR_SEQUENCE_CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel).toString().trim();
                    text.add(gettingText);
                } else if (methodName.equals(Constants.SET_TIME)) {
                    parcel.readInt();
                    String gettingText = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(new Date(parcel.readLong()));
                    text.add(gettingText);
                }

                parcel.recycle();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("NotificationClassifier", e.toString());
        }

        return text;
    }
```

This is working fine in android 4,5  but's its getting  crash on Android 7, Getting error like mAction field not available.

Please any one help me to solve this, I am stuck from two days.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using reflection to access method names and you are not switching the code for multiple platforms. The fields/methods that you are trying to access, change over time on multiple versions of the OS, so if you really want to have the reflection, you have to study what changes they were.

Generally, reflection should really be last resort, since on Android, the base code varies from version to version, and even from manufacturer to manufacturer.

Comment: okay, is there any other solution for this instead of reflection?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to read text messages from notification. if single message then i am getting through  android.text but if more then one message i am not getting it.

Comment: If you want to access other apps' notifications, you need to use `NotificationListenerService`. Example [here](https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example/)